# Swift 4 BLE centralManager didConnect

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

There are a couple relevant posts out there but none of them are helping me.. I am failing to successfully connect to my bluetooth device. The code looks like this:

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class WorkoutViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {

var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
var bikeDataPeripheral: CBPeripheral?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // bt initialization
    centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil) 
}

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    switch central.state {
    case .unknown:
        print("central.state is .unknown")
    case .resetting:
        print("central.state is .resetting")
    case .unsupported:
        print("central.state is .unsupported")
    case .unauthorized:
        print("central.state is .unauthorized")
    case .poweredOff:
        print("central.state is .poweredOff")
    case .poweredOn:
        print("central.state is .poweredOn")
        centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil)
    }
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    print(peripheral)
    if peripheral.name == "M3" {
        centralManager.stopScan()
        self.bikeDataPeripheral = peripheral
        bikeDataPeripheral?.delegate = self
        centralManager.connect(peripheral)
    }
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    print("Connected!")
    bikeDataPeripheral?.discoverServices(nil)
}
}
```

And the problem is that the "Connected!" message is never printed. It seems like I am getting stuck in a Connecting state but the phone never fully connects to the BLE device/peripheral

Comment: Have you confirmed that you are actually calling `connect`?  You should also implement [`didFailToConnect`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate/1518988-centralmanager)

Comment: @Paulw11 I believe 'connect' is being caled because I see the status changed to 'Connecting' from 'Disconnected'. I have also implemented didFailToConnect but my print statement in that method is never being called either

Comment: Your code looks correct.  Restart your phone and your peripheral and see if that helps.

Comment: You might also implement `centralManager:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:` containing a log message just to be thorough.